# Get Referral information from Google Analytics into web page?

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a client with a website that has an Inquiry form (name, email address, comments). The site will be hooked into Google Analytics as well.

Using GA, how can I get the referral information directly in the website at the time of form submission for that visitor? The client wants to know where the Inquiry first originated, and store that data on their end.

Is this possible with GA? I haven't found anything stating the contrary, but nothing on how to accomplish this, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible:
In the first step you have to connect the data from the form with the session information from GA. You could do this by sending a random number to GA and save the same in your database with the formular message. (I would store this as a Event in GA). 
If you have this number in both data-silos you can match them easy. Just query the GA API with the number you gave the form and ask for the Referrer (build a segment with the number).

You can also do this "realtime" by using the GA Realtime-API.

Comment: To further on this, you could parse the GA cookie to grab the CID (Client ID) and store that in the form (I'd also recommend a custom dimension scoped to the user too). Then you can associate all hits to their client ID. Particularly the User Explorer would be useful here.